# Oracle regular expression for number range and length

Tags: sql, regex, validation, oracle11g

I need to validate a given list of ip address.
The ip address should be in the range of 1.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Below is what I've done so far:

```
WITH T(VAL) AS
     ( SELECT '123.1235.231.234.12' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '123123' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '011' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '011.' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '000.' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '123123' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '192.168.1.65' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '255.256.1.65' FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(VAL,'^[1-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$')
 AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL, '[1-9]{1,3}',1,1) BETWEEN 1 AND 255
 AND regexp_substr(val, '[0-9]{1,3}',1,2) BETWEEN 0 AND 255
 AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL, '[0-9]{1,3}',1,3) BETWEEN 0 AND 255
 AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL, '[0-9]{1,3}',1,4) BETWEEN 0 AND 255
```

Its working fine with the data I tested.
Please help if I can do the same with simple regular expression.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your regex, it doesn't match `10.0.0.0` for example.

Change it to:

```
'^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

The test that follow will reject `0.0.0.0`

Comment: I find `^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$` is cleaner, rather than repeating the same pattern 3 times.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04: these cases are rejected with the existing second condition: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL, '[1-9]{1,3}',1,1) BETWEEN 1 AND 255`